# ggpubr, getting stat_compare_means to work with "fill" variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have this data:

```
Facelift<-structure(list(PercentDifference = c(10.126582278481, 8.33333333333335, 
8.25688073394495, 9.90099009900991, 5, 7.04225352112675, 0, 8.8888888888889, 
7.4074074074074, 5.05050505050506, -0.840336134453779, 14.4329896907217, 
5, 7.04225352112675, 0, 6.52173913043479, 17.5675675675675, 9.47368421052632, 
12.3809523809524, 21.978021978022, 5, 2.7027027027027, -5.55555555555557, 
4.25531914893618, 10, 8.42105263157895, 4.71698113207548, 4, 
-5.55555555555556, 1.2820512820513, 0, -3.88349514563107, 11.3924050632911, 
6.1855670103093, 5.71428571428572, 9.47368421052632, -5.55555555555556, 
1.2820512820513, 0, -2.94117647058822, 11.3924050632911, 10.752688172043, 
5.71428571428572, 13.0434782608696, -10.5263157894737, 2.5974025974026, 
1.61290322580645, -3.88349514563107, 5.63380281690142, 10.5769230769231, 
3.7037037037037, 5.55555555555556, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7.14285714285714, 
10.5769230769231, 2.75229357798163, 13.0952380952381, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 8.69565217391304, 8.49056603773586, 3.7037037037037, 
10.4651162790698, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8.43373493975903, 5.55555555555556, 
9.90099009900991, 8.33333333333333, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9.75609756097562, 
5.55555555555556, 7.76699029126213, 5.8139534883721, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 8.43373493975903, 5.55555555555556, 8.82352941176472, 
5.8139534883721, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.46913580246915, 6.1855670103093, 
7.54716981132075, 3.84615384615385, 0, 1.40845070422535, -3.84615384615385, 
1.09890109890109, 9.21052631578949, 10.752688172043, 5.55555555555556, 
10.2040816326531, 0, 0, -3.84615384615385, 0, 6.41025641025643, 
1.98019801980198, 1.7857142857143, 9.0909090909091, 0, 0, -1.96078431372548, 
-2.1276595744681, 3.75000000000001, 6.1855670103093, 4.67289719626167, 
17.0212765957447, 0, -1.49253731343284, 0, 0, 3.75000000000001, 
7.29166666666667, 3.7037037037037, 15.7894736842105, 6.25, -1.49253731343284, 
-1.92307692307694, 1.17647058823529, 6.41025641025643, 7.29166666666667, 
3.7037037037037, 15.7894736842105, 13.3333333333333, 0, -3.77358490566038, 
0, 10.2941176470588, 6.93069306930694, 10.0917431192661, 15, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 11.9402985074627, 4.85436893203883, 4.34782608695652, 
17.3469387755102, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15.3846153846154, 8.00000000000001, 
2.56410256410258, 11.6504854368932, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8.69565217391304, 
5, -1.81818181818181, 3.92156862745099, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7.14285714285714, 
7.14285714285714, -1.81818181818181, 3.92156862745099, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 7.14285714285714, 9.375, 1.88679245283019, 6.00000000000001, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.25, 5.7377049180328, 11.4035087719298, 14.1176470588235, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.25, 6.61157024793388, 10.4347826086956, 14.1176470588235, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.25, 7.5, 11.4035087719298, 14.1176470588235, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.52941176470589, 9.09090909090908, 4.54545454545454, 
15.1162790697674, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6.02409638554218, 11.1111111111111, 
4.54545454545454, 16.4705882352941, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.52941176470589, 
9.09090909090908, 1.76991150442478, 17.8571428571429, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 14.2857142857143, -1.96078431372548, -1.96078431372548, 
2.49999999999999, 11.1111111111111, 5.26315789473684, 0, 0, 14.2857142857143, 
0, 5.26315789473684, 2.49999999999999, 11.1111111111111, 14.2857142857143, 
1.92307692307692, 0, 17.6470588235294, 2.04081632653061, 6.38297872340425, 
9.33333333333333, 11.1111111111111, 17.6470588235294, 0, 2.27272727272727, 
7.14285714285714, 7.14285714285714, 0, 7.5, 11.1111111111111, 
16.6666666666667, 12.2448979591837, -1.09890109890109, 10.2941176470588, 
12.9032258064516, 5.55555555555556, 16.2162162162162, 25, 16.6666666666667, 
10, 7.14285714285714, 11.9402985074627, 15.3846153846154, 6.74157303370786, 
21.1267605633803, 25, 20.6896551724138, 10, 11.1111111111111, 
4.10958904109588, 3.80952380952382, 2, 2.35294117647058, 0, 6.06060606060606, 
0, 2.12765957446808, 7.04225352112675, 4.80769230769231, 2, 11.5384615384615, 
12.5, 6.06060606060606, 5.66037735849056, 2.12765957446808, 8.57142857142856, 
5.8252427184466, 4.08163265306121, 16, 12.5, 9.375, 9.80392156862746, 
20, 8.45070422535212, 0, -0.925925925925941, 2.22222222222221, 
-5, 9.0909090909091, 3.57142857142858, 4.3956043956044, 11.5942028985507, 
-0.884955752212402, 3.88349514563104, 8.23529411764705, -5, 2.85714285714287, 
9.43396226415094, 7.95454545454544, 16.6666666666667, 0, 3.88349514563104, 
13.5802469135802, -5, 2.85714285714287, 11.5384615384615, 10.4651162790698, 
-5.88235294117647, 4.16666666666667, 8.33333333333333, 16.8316831683168, 
0, 40, 0, 8.8888888888889, 0, 5.04201680672269, 8.33333333333333, 
19.1919191919192, 5.26315789473684, 55.5555555555555, 9.09090909090908, 
11.3636363636364, 8.10810810810809, 14.6788990825688, 14.0350877192982, 
22.9166666666667, 11.1111111111111, 47.3684210526316, 9.09090909090908, 
11.3636363636364, 6.02409638554218, 3.96039603960396, 6.66666666666667, 
10, 10, 0, -1.40845070422535, 3.33333333333334, 10, 3.96039603960396, 
26.7326732673267, 18.2795698924731, 10, 9.375, 7.69230769230769, 
3.33333333333334, 17.3333333333333, 5, 28, 29.4117647058824, 
10, 12.9032258064516, 7.69230769230769, 3.33333333333334, 0, 
0, 5.26315789473684, 9.41176470588236, 0, 0, 10, -2.10526315789473, 
0, 10.5263157894737, 5.26315789473684, 32.8571428571429, 0, 50, 
10, 16.25, 2.94117647058825, 12.9032258064516, 7.5268817204301, 
36.764705882353, 15.3846153846154, 100, 10, 24, 0, 4.76190476190477, 
6.79611650485437, 0, 42.8571428571429, 7.14285714285714, 2.04081632653061, 
2.27272727272727, 0, 10, 10, 20, 42.8571428571429, 20, 0, 4.65116279069768, 
0, 10, 10, 26.7605633802817, 66.6666666666667, 20, 0, 5.88235294117647, 
6.66666666666667, 0, 14.2857142857143, 5, 2.94117647058825, 2.04081632653061, 
6.66666666666667, 6.25, 14.2857142857143, 5, 2.94117647058825, 
3.09278350515465, 14.2857142857143, 6.25, 14.2857142857143, 5, 
2.94117647058825, 6.38297872340425, 12.6760563380282, 13.9240506329114, 
13.1578947368421, 4.6875, 8.69565217391304, 9.27835051546393, 
14.2857142857143, 18.421052631579, 22.8571428571428, 13.5593220338983, 
17.1875, 15.2173913043478, 23.0769230769231, 20, 30.3030303030303, 
11.6666666666667, 20.9677419354839, 17.7777777777778, 0, 0, 2.40963855421685, 
0, 2.5974025974026, 3.125, 2.4390243902439, 1.11111111111111, 
4.93827160493827, 4.16666666666667, 3.94736842105263, 3.125, 
6.32911392405062, 2.24719101123594, 4.93827160493827, 4.16666666666667, 
1.2820512820513, 5.3191489361702, -2.19780219780219, -4.04040404040404, 
-4.30107526881721, -3.8961038961039, -3.79746835443039, -4.62962962962963, 
8.53658536585367, 5.55555555555556, 5.95238095238095, 1.36986301369864, 
-2.56410256410257, 1.98019801980198, 11.25, 5.55555555555556, 
7.2289156626506, 2.77777777777779, 1.33333333333332, 3, 6.06060606060606, 
20, 6.06060606060606, 0, 5.79710144927534, 4.16666666666667, 
7.14285714285714, 23.7113402061856, 17.9775280898876, 27.4509803921569, 
8.95522388059702, 6.38297872340425, 15.3846153846154, 30.4347826086957, 
19.3181818181818, 32.6530612244898, 10.6060606060606, 6.38297872340425, 
6.00000000000001, 8.82352941176472, 8.42105263157895, -7.69230769230769, 
0, 3.03030303030303, 17.7777777777778, 15.625, 14.4444444444445, 
-6.25, 3.07692307692309, 6.25, 21.8390804597701, 23.3333333333333, 
21.1764705882353, -6.25, 3.07692307692309, 9.6774193548387, 20, 
11.1111111111111, 6.25, 0, 0, 0, 18.421052631579, 33.3333333333333, 
6.25, 8.33333333333333, 7.14285714285714, 5, 28.5714285714286, 
38.8888888888889, 13.3333333333333, 8.33333333333333, 7.14285714285714, 
7.14285714285714, 12.5, 9.41176470588236, 7.95454545454544, 0, 
4.28571428571429, 5, 20, 24, 15.8536585365854, 8.33333333333333, 
4.28571428571429, 10.5263157894737, 20, 16.25, 18.75, 8.33333333333333, 
4.28571428571429, 15.3846153846154), Direction = c("Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Horizontal", 
"Horizontal", "Horizontal", "Vertical", "Vertical", "Vertical"
), Paper = structure(c(2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 
7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 
2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 
10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 
8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 
14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 
9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 
3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 
1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 
7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 
2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 
10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 
8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 
14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 
9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 
3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 
1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 
7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 
2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 
10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 
8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 
14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 
9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 
3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 
1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 
7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 
2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 
10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 
8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 
14L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 
12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 
6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 
11L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 
12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 
6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 
11L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 
12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 
6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 
11L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 
12L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 13L, 12L), .Label = c("NA - ELB", "LC - HR", 
"OC - EL", "ME - ELB", "ML - EL", "NLF - ELB", "NS - ST", "NA", 
"LC", "OC", "ME", "ML", "NLF", "NS"), class = "factor"), Area = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Upper Face", 
"Midface", "Lower Face"), class = "factor"), Procedure = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Skin", 
"SMAS", "Extended"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -576L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And I'm trying to recreate this table that someone else made in other software, but we'd like to change it to a boxplot.

[image]

This code gets me most of the way there:

```
Facelift%>%filter(Direction=="Horizontal")%>%ggplot(aes(x=Paper,y=PercentDifference, fill=Procedure))+geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)+facet_grid(.~Area,scales = "free_x")+labs(y="Percent Difference", x= "Measurement")
```

[image]

But as you can see, I still need to add significance bars to emulate the other table.  I've looked into ggsignif and ggpubr to do this, and it seems like stat_compare_means should get me close, but it seems like (what I can tell from googling) that stat_compare_means can only really work with values that ggplot thinks are in the "X",  NOT variables being used for the "fill".   For instance if I do this code prior:

```
my_comparisons = list( c("Skin", "SMAS"), c("Skin", "Extended"), c("SMAS", "Extended") )
```

And then add this code to my graph:

```
+stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons)
```

Nothing happens.  But if I switch the x and the "fill" variables, lines show up.

I need to show lines comparing the operative technique (i.e. the fill variables) without rearranging my plot, how can I accomplish this? Can I?  Thank you!